# Samba Domain Member Slow Authentication

Tags: 16.04, networking, samba, domain-server, samba4

I have a Samba 4 domain controller set up with about 100 member computers connected to it on a private LAN.

As I was rolling this out, I found a couple clients that were improperly configured with the wrong DNS address after a reboot and it took about 10 minutes to log in as a local user to fix it.  Is there any kind of timeout that you can configure to make that 30s or less?  I need all of these machines to allow local users to log on relatively quickly.

Comment: If most computers were connectiong quickly but that for a couple of others  it took 10 min. to others, the problem lies most probabably on the client side, not on the SAMBA side.  Are these windows computers?

Comment: No these are Ubuntu machines.  I think they took forever because the DNS was improperly configured and they couldn't reach the domain controller.  I just want it to attempt local authentication first or timeout faster if it can't react the CD.